# Print all possible substrings that has exactly k distinct characters (irrespective of size)

Tags: java, string, data-structures, substring, sliding-window

This is my code:

```
public static List<String> findSubstrings(String str, int k) {
         ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
         HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

         int start = 0, end = 0;

         while(end < str.length()) {
             char ch = str.charAt(end);

             int count = map.getOrDefault(ch, 0);
             map.put(ch, count+1);

             if (map.size() == k) {
                 list.add(str.substring(start, end+1));
             }
             else if (map.size() > k) {
                 char startChar = str.charAt(start);

                 while(map.size() != k) {
                     map.put(startChar, map.get(startChar) - 1);
                     start++;

                     if (map.get(startChar) == 0) {
                         map.remove(startChar);
                         list.add(str.substring(start, end+1));
                     }
                     startChar = str.charAt(start);
                 }
             }
             end++;
         }
        return list; 
     }
```

findSubstrings("ababbacac", 2): 
[ab, aba, abab, ababb, ababba, ac, aca, acac]

I'm not handling a case where once end of current window hits string end, substring between current start and end satisfying the criteria, are not printed out. How to handle that case without another while loop?
Also, please help me know if its not O(n).

Thanks

Comment: You have to be more specific with your problem statement. What about `ba`, for example? Is it also a substring?

Comment: @STF Yes, "ba" is also valid substring.